# Display multiple field slug types_render_field in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I create a type group in which I insert an image field with img slug that you can create multiple instances.
Now my problem is that I want to display for example only one field value of img slug field.
Using

```
types_render_field('img', array())
```

it show all flied i insert for img slug field.
I also tried with

```
types_render_field('img[0], array());
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instad of using types_render_field I access to custom fields value using get_post_custom function.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem, finally find this solution if someone need :

```
types_render_field('photos', array("index" => 0));
```